# nonnegative option in a function of an ODE

Tags: matlab, function, ode

As it is specified in the title I need to force a function to be always positive (if it runs into negative it has to equal 0). This function is inside an ODE:

This is the script from where I call the ODE:

```
clear
t=[0,276];   
Tie=0.3;
mumax=2;
Qmin=1;
X0=[4,2];
[t,X]=ode45(@(t,X) odeset(mumax,Qmin,Tie,X),t,X0);
```

This is the function that I want to keep always positive

```
function [ func2 ] = func2 (mumax,Qmin,Q)

func2=mumax*(1-Qmin/Q);

end
```

and this is the ODE

```
function [ dXdt ] = odeset(mumax, Qmin, Tie,X) 

dXdt=zeros(2,1);
dXdt(1)=func2(mumax,Qmin,X(1))-X(2)*Tie;
dXdt(2)=func2(mumax,Qmin,X(1))-X(2)*Tie;
end
```

Comment: There's a builtin option that does exactly this in a robust manner. [See here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/nonnegative-ode-solution.html). However, you're also overloading Matlab's [`odeset`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html) that is used to set parameters and options like `'NonNegative'` for the various ODE solvers. You'll want to change the name of your your ODE function. Finally, it looks like the two derivatives in your ODE function are identical.

Comment: the ODE are just an example that makes no sense, I am not working with that.
Also, your link is to make the solution of the ODE always positive, but I dont want that, I just want the func2 to be always positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `func2`'s output to

```
function [ out ] = func2 (mumax,Qmin,Q)
    out=max(mumax*(1-Qmin/Q),0);
end
```

This will force the output to be positive or Zero.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your contribution, but I think the expression in brackets in the max function should be the other way round:
`function [ out ] = func2 (mumax,Qmin,Q)
    out=max(mumax*(1-Qmin/Q),0);
end`

This way you say that the minimum value allowed is 0 (or any other number you write in that part of the expression). I found that information in this [link](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html#bupr915).

Please, confirm or correct me if I am wrong and I will mark your coment as the right answer.

Comment: @kumbu, what do you mean by the other way round? Where would you modify func2's output to make it non negative?

Comment: yes, sorry I press intro before finnishing my coment, look at the edited coment. Basically is writing `out=max(mumax*(1-Qmin/Q),0)`; instead of `out=max(0,mumax*(1-Qmin/Q))`;

Comment: @kumbu both orders should give the same output. If you prefer, I will change my answers order